# Can we use the port number with (back slash)/8080 with the Apache url like http://127.0.0./5000/

Tags: apache-2.2, url

Can we use the port number with (back slash)/8080 with the Apache url like http://127.0.0.0/8080/

ab http://127.0.0.0/8080/

will it take 8080 as application port number or it will take the 80 as http default port number

Comment: what you could do is put reverse proxy in apache and map the /8080 path => a vhost with a reverse proxy listening to localhost:8080 and thus you'd use the http default port 80 but it'd be proxied to the :8080 app

Comment: Also, `/` is the 'slash' and `\\` is the 'backslash'.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for specifying a port number in a URL is to add ":port" after the hostname (or IP address) and before the first slash, if present:

http://server.domain.com:8080
http://server.domain.com:8080/
http://server.domain.com:8080/path/path

http://127.0.0.1:8080/ will connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 8080 and retrieve the web site root.
http://127.0.0.1/8080/ will connect to 127.0.0.1 on the standard port (80) and retrieve the web site at path "/8080".

This is not specific to Apache, or even to HTTP; it's the standard format for [URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).

Answer (score 2):

No, because trying to connect to `http://127.0.0.1/8080/` will make your browser try to access the directory `/8080` on the default http port, 80.

However, `http://127.0.0.1:8080` will direct you to the root of your server on port 8080, as mentioned by the [RFC for URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.3)